# jitsi not supported in IOS xamarin webview

Tags: ios, xamarin, browser, cross-browser, jitsi

I am trying to open jitsi website on a webview,

if I open it in the Safari builtin browser, it works fine.

if I open it in a Webview inside Xamarin application, it said "It looks like you're using a browser we don't fully support"

is not it supposed the Webview uses Safari by default?
then, why Safari works, while the Webview is not supported?

Is there any work around to open the Jitsi inside the application Webview?

Opening an external browser is not an option,

------------ UPDATE (1) -----------------

According to Jason advice, I set the UserAgent:

1- I used my xamarin webview and navigate to:

whatsmyua.info

My UserAgent was "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"

2- I used iPhone Safari and navigate to:

whatsmyua.info

My UserAgent was "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

3- So I set the xamarin webview UserAgent in code behind
wkWebView.CustomUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1";

4- I check again using "whatsmyua.info", and everythign is ok, UserAgent successfully changed.

5- I tried to open "jitsi website", but nothing changed,
still gives me "It looks like you're using a browser we don't fully support"

Any Ideas, please?

===================== Update (2) ========================

I used UserAgent "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i586; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0",

Now it is working,
But I do not why it did not work when I used the same UserAgent like Safari!

Anyway, I am happy

Thanks (Jason)

Comment: you probably need to set the `UserAgent` header to something supported by the site

Comment: looks interesting, can you provide some example, please.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=wkwebview+user+agent

Comment: Check my comment below, please

Comment: According to Jason advice, I set the UserAgent:

1- I used my xamarin webview and navigate to:

whatsmyua.info

My UserAgent was "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"

2- I used iPhone Safari and navigate to:

whatsmyua.info

My UserAgent was "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

Comment: 3- So I set the xamarin webview UserAgent in code behind
wkWebView.CustomUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1";

4- I check again using "whatsmyua.info", and everythign is ok, UserAgent successfully changed.

5- I tried to open "jitsi website", but nothing changed,
still gives me "It looks like you're using a browser we don't fully support"


Any Ideas, pleas?

Comment: I sent them as Question update, check please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Jason advice, I set the UserAgent:

1- I used my xamarin webview and navigate to:

whatsmyua.info

My UserAgent was "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148"

2- I used iPhone Safari and navigate to:

whatsmyua.info

My UserAgent was "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"

3- So I set the xamarin webview UserAgent in code behind wkWebView.CustomUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.5 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1";

4- I check again using "whatsmyua.info", and everythign is ok, UserAgent successfully changed.

5- I tried to open "jitsi website", but nothing changed, still gives me "It looks like you're using a browser we don't fully support"

===================== Final Working Solution ========================

I used this UserAgent:
wkWebView.CustomUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i586; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";

Now it is working!

Anyway, I am happy

Thanks (Jason)